# cascade delete not firing trigger

Tags: mysql, postgresql

One of the reasons I moved to postgresql was that (unlike mysql) foreign key actions (e.g. cascade delete) can fire triggers.

In my database I have the tables 'penalty_kicks' where the foreign key references 'player_instance':

```
ALTER TABLE penalty_kicks ADD FOREIGN KEY (kicker_id) REFERENCES player_instance (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I know that this works as when I delete a player_instance every associated row for penalty_kicks is deleted.

I also have a trigger function where if a row for penalty_kicks is deleted then it will alter a row for 'scores':

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_penalty_kicks AFTER DELETE ON penalty_kicks FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_kicks();

CREATE FUNCTION delete_kicks()
RETURNS trigger AS $temp$
BEGIN

    UPDATE scores s
    SET    points = points -3
    FROM   player_instance pi
    WHERE  pi.id = OLD.kicker_id
    AND    s.match_id = pi.match_id 
    AND    s.team_id  = pi.team_id 
    AND    OLD.success;         
RETURN NULL;         

END;
$temp$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

(big thanks to another user for the above)

I know that this works as when I delete a row for penalty_kicks it will perform the correct action on score.

However, when I delete a player_instance it will only delete the penalty_kick (by the cascade) and not fire the trigger to alter scores.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It is not possible what you are talking about! Perhaps you have also a delete cascade from player_instance to scores table, that way all scores of your just deleted player are gone too!  So please update your question by adding a full example (tables DDL...)

Comment: @Houari - no, the scores are still there (and are supposed to be)

Comment: Ok! When the trigger is fired on your `penalty_kicks`, the record which value is value is `OLD.kicker_id` in your `player_instance` table does not exist anymore (in this transaction isolation) it was deleted before arriving to trigger execution! This is why the update is not affecting any rows because there is no `pi.id = OLD.kicker_id`. 
The trigger is fired anyway!
I think that is an issue about your tables design, not the trigger firing on cascade delete on PG :)

Comment: You want a `before delete` trigger, not an `after delete`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks but it still isn't working. I'm returning OLD in the above trigger. Is that correct?

Comment: ah, the problem being that even using BEFORE DELETE will still be after the deletion of player_instance and therefore the trigger function won't work. any ideas? http://kevinlocke.name/bits/2013/02/12/postgresql-cascading-delete-trigger-visibility/